# Merge multiple video assets with correct orientation swift

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avasset, avmutablecomposition

I am simply trying to stitch together (merge) an array of videos (**with correct original orientations**), and it works **HOWEVER with incorrect orientation of some videos**. For example with the current preferredTransform, front facing videos are inverted (i.e. if you filmed a video with your hand on the left, it will now be on the right..) while back camera videos are as they were originally.

*I have tried looking at so many questions on this, but none seem to fix the issue. I just need the videos to keep their original orientation!*

```
func merge(arrayVideos:[AVAsset], completion:@escaping (URL?, Error?) -> ()) {


          let mainComposition = AVMutableComposition()
          let compositionVideoTrack = mainComposition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: .video, preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid)
  compositionVideoTrack?.preferredTransform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: (.pi)/2) 

          let soundtrackTrack = mainComposition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: .audio, preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid)

            var insertTime = CMTime.zero

          for videoAsset in arrayVideos {
            try! compositionVideoTrack?.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(start: .zero, duration: videoAsset.duration), of: videoAsset.tracks(withMediaType: .video)[0], at: insertTime)
            try! soundtrackTrack?.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(start: .zero, duration: videoAsset.duration), of: videoAsset.tracks(withMediaType: .audio)[0], at: insertTime)

            insertTime = CMTimeAdd(insertTime, videoAsset.duration)
          }

          let outputFileURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory() + "merge.mp4")

          let fileManager = FileManager()
          try? fileManager.removeItem(at: outputFileURL)

          let exporter = AVAssetExportSession(asset: mainComposition, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality)

          exporter?.outputURL = outputFileURL
          exporter?.outputFileType = AVFileType.mp4
          exporter?.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = true

          exporter?.exportAsynchronously {
            if let url = exporter?.outputURL{
                completion(url, nil)
            }
            if let error = exporter?.error {
                completion(nil, error)
            }
          }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue!!

**Refer to my answer here:**

[How to correctly orient multiple video tracks (taken on front facing cam and back facing), before merging or during?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63588560/how-to-correctly-orient-multiple-video-tracks-taken-on-front-facing-cam-and-bac/63625731#63625731)

Comment: link invalid, any updated link or can you post the code?